# how to check if value of props exist or not in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<NavLink to={{pathname:"/topic",state:{index:index}}}>Topic</NavLink>
// class compononet
 constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {

        index:props.location.state.index

    };

}
```

i am passing state to react class component, i want to check if state value passsed or not,
    i tried if else but it gives error when value is not passsed,please someone tell me how to check this 
    with showing error
    i want to check this.props.location.state.index  exist or not

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'index' of undefined
```

Comment: Did you wrap your component using `withRouter` before exporting it?

Comment: no i didn't wrap

Comment: Try doing it? hmm..

Comment: whats the purpose of doing this

Comment: hey, did my answer solve your question?

Comment: no same issue occur again